# Enumerate files in mapped drive

Tags: c#, .net

I have a mapped network drive. This drive is mapped to letter "x:". 
Now, in my C# program i Have this line:

```
var ff = Directory.EnumerateFiles ("X:\\files", "*.*");
```

and I recived an `DirectoryNotFoundException` exception.

Any idea about how can I enumerate the files in a mapped network drive?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing special for *mapped network drives*

Comment: Does your application have permissions to access the drive? Does this user even have this drive mapped?

Comment: Is a win application?

Comment: Is there a folder called files in the root of X:?

Comment: Yes. This folder exists and the permissions is ok for the user that runs the program

Comment: try this @"x:\files\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can used like this

```
var filenames4 =  System.IO.Directory
            .EnumerateFiles("X:\\files\\", "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Select(System.IO.Path.GetFileName); 

 foreach (var file in filenames4)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", file);
        }
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using something like this but, for clear purposes in my question I only describe this line. This is the best way for me.

Comment: I solved this problem because I has a problem in my mapping credentials.